# use variable to include dynamic CSS

Tags: php, css

I am trying to find a way to let php choose and include the correct CSS based on factors I included in a function which can be printed by the variable $test.

What I would like to do is to use another variable for example so that I can simply include $test to print the file I would like to be included. for example for a static version of this I could simply do:

```
$test_static = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/test1.css" type="text/css">';
```

> echo $test_static;

however I would like to change the test1.css to what would be printed if I were to print the variable $test. If for example I were to print $test I would get value but I would need to add all the other bit before and after 1 in order to include the corresponding css file (ie 1.css)?

Comment: Are you trying to get the content from a CSS file and print it between `<style>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to do this, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
$test_static = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/' . $test . '" type="text/css">';
```

Comment: hi, this may work but I am trying with this but I need to add the .css at the end of $test. Any ideas?

Comment: Either append it to the variable, i.e. `$test .= ".css"` or in the string I provided in the answer, i.e. ...`"CSS/' . $test . '.css" type=`...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$file = 'test1.css';
if($someCondition == true) {
    $file = 'test2.css';
}

$test_static = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/' .

    $file .

    '" type="text/css">';
```